# How to Calculate Numbers from Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have column "P_L" in mysql with numbers about profit or loss and column "Status" with status - if these numbers are postive or negative.

Explanation: 50 Profit = + 50 , 30 Loss = - 30

I tried to calculate these numbers to get total profit/loss but something doesn't work. Output of the code down below is: + 50 - 30 + 50 - 25 - 15

So, how to calulcate P_L column? Is such a thing even possible?

Thank you!

Table looks something like that:

```
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------+
|   Id  |   Date Added  |   P_L  |   Status  |
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------+
|   1   |   2017-12-2   |   50   |   Profit  |
|   2   |   2017-12-3   |   30   |   Loss    |
|   3   |   2017-12-4   |   50   |   Profit  |
|   4   |   2017-12-5   |   25   |   Loss    |
|   5   |   2017-12-6   |   15   |   Loss    |
+-------+---------------+--------+-----------+
```

Piece of my PHP code..

```
.
.
.
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {  

    $id = $row['id'];
    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
    $p_l = $row['p_l'];
    $status = $row['status'];

    if($status == 'Profit') {
      $number = "+ $p_l";

    } elseif($status == 'Loss') {
      $number = "- $p_l";

    } 

    $total =  $number . " ";
    echo "$total";

   }
```

Comment: `times minus one` is a common approach. For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You should keep P & L in two columns so you could sum them much simpler. It's still possible now to get the result straight from MySQL not in PHP.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Answer (score 1):

You can sum the P_L column in the MySQL query [using IF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
SELECT SUM(IF(Status = 'Profit', P_L, -1 * P_L)) AS profit_and_loss FROM tableName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the total outside the loop.

Create a placeholder/container that starts from zero then add/subtract according to the actual value:

Be guided by the following code, this convert `p_l` column to its [`floatval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) since you did not provide table structure.

```
$total = 0; # placeholder
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  {  

    $id = $row['id'];
    $date_added = $row['date_added'];
    $p_l = $row['p_l'];
    $status = $row['status'];

    $number = floatval($p_l);

    if($status == 'Profit') {
      $total = $total + $number;

    } elseif ($status == 'Loss') {
      $total = $total - $number;
    } 

}
echo "$total";
```

Comment: @The Wolf Ohhhh yes! Thank you :)